# Error matching with downcasting the struct error types in AWS SDK

Tags: rust, aws-sdk-rust

I have this code in Go:

```
_, err := kms.ScheduleKeyDeletion(...
ev, ok := err.(awserr.Error)
deleted := false
if ok {
    switch ev.Code() {
        case "KMSInvalidStateException":
            deleted = strings.Contains(aerr.Message(), "pending deletion")
        case "NotFoundException":
            deleted = true
    }
}
```

Basically, want to do the same in Rust using https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/client/struct.Client.html#method.schedule_key_deletion

```
let result = cli.schedule_key_deletion().send().await;
let success = match result {
  Ok(ok_result) => { ... },
  Err(e) => {
    // "e" is the 'aws_sdk_kms::error::ScheduleKeyDeletionError' type
    // ref. https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/struct.ScheduleKeyDeletionError.html
    match e {
      // doesn't compile...
      aws_sdk_kms::error::NotFoundException => {
        true
      },
      _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, on the return type https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/struct.ScheduleKeyDeletionError.html, I want to check if the return struct is https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/struct.NotFoundException.html or not.

```
#[non_exhaustive]
pub struct ScheduleKeyDeletionError {
    pub kind: ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind,
    /* private fields */
}
```

```
#[non_exhaustive]
pub struct NotFoundException {
    pub message: Option<String>,
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`e.kind()` to get the *Kind of error that occurred*](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/struct.ScheduleKeyDeletionError.html#structfield.kind). The return value of `e.kind` will be of `Enum` type [`ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind`](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/enum.ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind.html). So you can match the [enum variant
`aws_sdk_kms::error::ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind::NotFoundException`](https://docs.rs/aws-sdk-kms/latest/aws_sdk_kms/error/enum.ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind.html#variant.NotFoundException) to see if there an `NotFoundException` Exception.

```
let result = cli.schedule_key_deletion().send().await;
let success = match result {
  Ok(ok_result) => { ... },
  Err(e) => {
    match e.kind() {
      aws_sdk_kms::error::ScheduleKeyDeletionErrorKind::NotFoundException(_)=> {
        true
      },
      _ => false
    }
  }
}
```

Note: This solution is not tested.